# Creación de usuarios no funciona Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel, laravel-excel

Buenas Comunidad.
Actualmente estoy en el desarrollo de un aplicativo web de contratos, la información de estos contratos la tomo de un archivo excel de esta extensión www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs .

Estoy realizando un proceso de migración de datos igual que con los contratos, para la creación de usuarios, solo tomando los valores de nombre de empleado y documento de identidad, pero no me funciona.

Tambien tengo un codigo en mi `routes.php` y este codigo si funciona pero toma los datos de una tabla que ya no se usa.

**routes.php**

```
Route::get("user_mig", function()
{
    temporalestla\User::truncate();
    $contr = temporalestla\ContractUser::all();
    foreach ($contr as $value)
    {
        $psw = \Hash::make($value->id_employee);
        $user = new temporalestla\User
        ([
            "full_name"=>$value->name_used,
            "user" => $value->id_employee,
            "password" => $psw,
            "perfil" => 1
        ]);
        $user->save();
    }
});
```

**ImportController.php**

```
public function cargar_datos_users(Request $request)
    {
        $archivo = $request->file('archivo');
        $nombre_original=$archivo->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension=$archivo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $r1=Storage::disk('archivos')->put($nombre_original,  \File::get($archivo) );
        $ruta  =  storage_path('archivos') ."/". $nombre_original;
        if($r1)
        {
            Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($ruta, function($hoja)
            {
                $hoja->each(function($fila)
                {
                    $pass = \Hash::make($fila->empleado);
                    $user = new User;
                    $user->full_name = $fila->nombreempleado;
                    $user->user = $fila->empleado;
                    $user->password = $pass;
                    $user->perfil = 1;
                    $user->save();
                });
            });
            return view("administrator.contracts.adminpayrolls")->with("msj","Usuarios Cargados Correctamente");             
        }
        else
        {
            return view("administrator.contracts.adminpayrolls")->with("msj","Error al subir el archivo");
        }
    }
```

**app/User.php**

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['full_name', 'user', 'password','perfil'];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
}
```

**Script con Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("submit",".formarchivo",function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formu=$(this);
        var nombreform=$(this).attr("id");
        if(nombreform=="f_cargar_datos_users" ){ var miurl="cargar_datos_users";  var divresul="notificacion_resul_fcdu"}
        var formData = new FormData($("#"+nombreform+"")[0]);
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: miurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $("#"+divresul+"").html($("#cargador_empresa").html());
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert("Usuarios cargados correctamente");
                location.reload(true);
            },
            error: function(data)
            {
                alert("Error al subir usuarios. intente nuevamente");
                location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

He intentado muchas formas para poder tomar los valores del archivo excel e insertarlos en la base de datos pero ninguno ha tenido exito, salvo el codigo de routes.php que tampoco me funciona implementandolo con la misma sintaxis.

Cualquier comentario es bienvenido, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿qué es lo que no funciona exactamente? ¿algún mensaje de error?

Comment: No esta insertando los datos en la base de datos, el mensaje de error que me retorna es el del script de ajax, no puedo ver el error que retorna laravel. 
Sin embargo no se si estoy implementando bien la parte de la encriptación de la contraseña. Como mencioné, utilizo el mismo proceso en la migración de contratos y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Sería interesante ver el mensaje de error de Laravel en caso que lo haya, simplemente busca en el log respectivo.

Comment: Lo habia intentado antes y no podia, ahora si pude conseguir el log, es el siguiente:

`[2017-04-11 10:48:17] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded' in /home/tempor/core_temporales/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php:30`

Comment: 30 segundos de ejecución no fueron suficientes? ummm algo está mal y no pareciera ser Laravel.

Comment: Hasta donde se, los servidores tienen máximo 30 segundos para ejecutar consultas, es así?

Comment: No, no es así, es un simple parámetro de configuración de PHP / servidor web. En todo caso si ese proceso está tomando más de 30 segundos, algo está mal en otra parte. ¿es así de lento el servidor? ¿hay muchos procesos simultáneos? ¿qué servidor web es? ¿qué versión de php?

Comment: El servidor esta corriendo **php** 5.4.40, **mysql** 5.6.35, **OS** linux, te comento, acabo de realizar pruebas con la parte de encriptación, en el proceso de contratos le agregue encriptación a una columna X y se rompio el proceso, pienso que el problema es en la ejecución del encriptamiento, que opinas tú? Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda de antemano!

Comment: El proceso en realidad no es nada complejo, de un archivo excel tomaria dos valores, nombre y numero de documento, una tercera columna que se encripta el numero de documento y se toma como contraseña, y por ultimo una constante.